# What's the meaning of the leaving the last parameter empty when creating a numpy array using functions like np.zeros or np.ones?

Tags: python, numpy, initialization

When we initialize numpy arrays using np.zeros or np.ones, we may leave the last dimension unspecified.

The following are examples:

```
 x1 = np.zeros((4, ))
 x2 = np.zeros((4, 3, ))
```

But the following doesn't work

```
 x3 = np.zeros(( , 4))
 x4 = np.zeros(( 4, , ))
```

I'm not quite sure what the purpose of leaving the last dimension unspecified is. It seems like there is no difference between `np.zeros((4, )`) and `np.zeros((4))`, so I don't clearly understand the reason of leaving the last dimenion unspecified. Could anyone clarify on this?

Comment: That's not "leaving the last dimension unspecified". There **is no** second dimension in that array; `(4,)` is Python syntax for a length-1 tuple with single element `4`, and passing that to `numpy.zeros` produces a 1-dimensional array of length 4.

Comment: The docs say this parameter can be a `sequence` or integer.  `(1,)` is a 1 element sequence.  So is `[1]`.  `1` is an integer.  All 3 produce an array with shape `(1,)` (shape is always a tuple).  Evidently there's some sort of internal tweaking of inputs to a common logical form.